# How to save password in browser (https)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, https

How to make browser prompt to save password, save password in browser and load password while opening page next time
***https://localhost:port/xxxxx***

On all other pages its saving password including http://localhost:port/xxxxx

Browser: Chrome

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Password are not saved in browser when code is ran on local and browsed using https. Its saved in all other cases, If `http`://localhost:port/xxxxx is used password is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Use your PC's Ip address instead of localhost

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).